# Secure openSSL file encryption

Tags: powershell, encryption, openssl, aes

I wish to encrypt gigabytes of data with OpenSSL (multiple files), securely.

I use this command (openSSL 1.0.2p-i386-win32):

```
openssl.exe enc -e -aes-256-ctr -in secret.txt -out encrypted.txt -salt -pass pass:AsIDHnd19!&@#@!#lJglG1f31!
```

My questions are:

1. What mode to use? CTR or CBC? (CTR for speed?)
2. How to generate random IVs? For example in a PowerShell script. (I am using Pshell v2.0)
3. Is the command I provided secure enough?
4. Can I use the same salt for every file, for better encryption speed?
5. Does a 20-30 char truly random password compensate for the lack of
   IV?

EDIT:

I downloaded a newer version, with ability to use PBKDF2 (openSSL 1.1.1-win32-mingw):

```
openssl.exe enc -e -aes-256-ctr -in secret.txt -out encrypted.txt -salt -pass pass:AsIDHnd19!&@#@!#lJglG1f31! -pbkdf2 -p
```

With -p I can see the salt, key and IV that's used to encrypt the file. All 3 parameters change every time I run openssl, even if on the same file and with the same pass.

Does that mean I'm safe now and IV is random?

Comment: A password of 20-30 random char's suggest that it ain't a password that only exists in some users head, but is something that is stored somewhere. In that case you should just use an actuall binary AES key. AES itself don't use passwords, and OpenSSL needs to do a lot of extra stuff to turn your password into a key .. eg. adding a salt, and doing some password stretching etc.. You get alot of extra processing for atmost the same security.

Comment: Is this how to generate an AES key? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979457/aes-encryption-on-files-using-powershell This is another one of my questions. So now that I have generated it, i just feed the key to the -k tag in openssl or what? And btw the password is randomly generated and saved on another machine.

Comment: I run the previous command but add a -p tag to see iv, key and salt, every time i encrypt the same file with the same password all 3 parameters change randomly. That means I'm safe and openssl generates randomly for me?

Comment: @kelalaka Ok thanks. That means I can encrypt securely with this command?

Comment: @kelalaka I need to execute it from the command line, without interactive mode. Is reading the password from a file and then shredding the file safer? Using the tagg -pass file:FILEPATH

Comment: @kelalaka I keep seeing online that it's considered the best and fastest one. Isn't it no big deal since now I have  a random IV?

Comment: According to that, ctr is better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. CBC and CTR should have same speed around.
2. If not specified IV is generated from your password with pbkdf2.
3. CTR is [recommended](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/aes-cbc-mode-or-aes-ctr-mode-recommended) to CBC.
4. Using the same salt is not adviced. Salt used to prevent attacks for the password, from OpenSSL documentation.

> Without the -salt option it is possible to perform efficient dictionary attacks on the password and to attack stream cipher encrypted data. The reason for this is that without the salt the same password always generates the same encryption key. When the salt is being used the first eight bytes of the encrypted data are reserved for the salt: it is generated at random when encrypting a file and read from the encrypted file when it is decrypted.

5. IV is not lack of. OpenSLL generates is for you if not given.